# Using Shared Preferences to save a high score in an Android game

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have made an android game and wish to save highscores using Shared preferences. I have created a class which `extends Application` but receive a null pointer exception on:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I would appreciate some example code on how to save and load shared preferences as other examples are causing this null pointer exception.

```
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-17335
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at MyApplication.save(MyApplication.java:22)
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at GameScreen.drawGameOverUI(GameScreen.java:609)
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at GameScreen.paint(GameScreen.java:493)
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:48)
06-12 17:53:55.864: E/AndroidRuntime(13923):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done in a couple of lines:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_POSITION, position).commit();
```

Where `APP_NAME` is a String, `SELECTED_POSITION` is another String and position an int, which I want to store.

And to get it:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getInt(SELECTED_POSITION, 0);
```

Comment: Does this code need to be in an application or can it be anywhere as I am still getting a null pointer exception in my application class and in the class i wish to save and load highscores im getting "MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable" when I put the save method in there

Comment: I use it on my Activity.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials on Android game development as I think the problem could be being caused by the one I followed

Comment: No, I do not. I bet if you search on Google you'll find a good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;
int mylevel
```

in oncreate

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Global.PREFERENCE_NAME,
                MODE_PRIVATE);
loadSavedPrefs();
```

my load method

```
private void loadSavedPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//first value is the key or name value is under. second value is the default value if their //is no instance of this key already.
        mylevel = sharedPreferences.getInt("level", 10);


    }
```

saving looks like this

```
private void save() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        editor.putInt("level", mylevel);

        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

best to call save in onpause(so it saves when closed, but for highscores u can call it from any method such as when the game ends and the win screen is shown

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        save();

        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting errors with "PREFERENCE_NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field", eclipse is giving me 40 suggestions of what to change it to

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("your_app_name_string", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then you can set a value like in a HashMap like this

```
prefs.edit().putInt("score", points).commit(); //"score" is a key and 'points' is a variable set by you.
```

And to retrieve you can use

```
prefs.getInt("score", 0); //You pass the string you used as key and a default value.
```

HIH